# Stuck while reading data from stream

Tags: java, eclipse, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I have these lines of code in Eclipse

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>()
while (in.hasNextInt())
{
    int a = in.nextInt();
    list.add(a);
}
// something more to do here
```

I'm just solving some problems on an internet's site using their compiler. When I ran the code, the result came normally, but it's wrong, so I want to check my code again by Eclipse's debugger. Strangely when I ran the code in Eclipse, it stopped right after adding everything to the list, without proceeding to "something more to do here". Can anyone explain me why ? I even checked to F5, F6, or F8, but nothing happened. Do I have to press something else after that ?

Comment: You have to send EOF from the keyboard. On Windows it's `^Z[Enter]` and on Linux it's `^D`.

Comment: Alternatively, enter a `String` like "`Fred`".

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop will continue accepting characters as there is no exit condition.
You can either 
1. add an exit condition to get out of the while loop
2. send an EOF by Ctrl+Z 
3. type something thats not an int.